# Can someone provide a resource to study how to prove math equations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, online-resources

Right now I am taking an algorithms class. However my university does not provide a discrete math course. To make matters a little rougher, proofs and induction had barely been touched by any of my computer science courses.

If possible, could you provide a few links to learn this concept from?

Comment: Take a look at Velleman's *How to Prove It: A Structured Approach.*  It covers proofs and proofs by induction, and covers basic logic early on.

Comment: @amWhy You should just go ahead and post that as an answer. A glance over the book and it looks like it may be helpful.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at Rosen's *Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications*. It's great for an overview of Discrete Mathematics.  Between this text and Vellemans text, you'll learn most of what you need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my initial comment:

Take a look at Velleman's ***[How to Prove It: A Structured Approach.](http://users.metu.edu.tr/serge/courses/111-2011/textbook-math111.pdf)*** It covers proofs using a variety of methods, including proofs by induction, and covers basic logic early on.

You might also want to take a look at Rosen's ***[Discrete Mathematics and Its Application](http://www2.fiit.stuba.sk/~kvasnicka/Mathematics%20for%20Informatics/Rosen_Discrete_Mathematics_and_Its_Applications_7th_Edition.pdf)s***. It's great for an overview of Discrete Mathematics.  Between this text and Velleman's text, you'll learn most of what you need to know or to reference.

Comment: You might want to add to your answer [this link](http://users.metu.edu.tr/serge/courses/111-2011/textbook-math111.pdf) to the pdf.

Comment: @heather Hmmm, I'm a little reluctant, not knowing how or by whom the pdf of the text came to be; the course providing the pdf of the text may have obtained a license of use in the specific course being taught, but was likely not approved for the general public.  I'm just being cautious.

Comment: That's your choice; I do know that Rosen has a companion site to go along with the text; but use of it might require signing up and providing a code from the text (like IBN number). You can keep your link here if for now ...I'll check on it further, and if there are any problems with passing the link along, I'll let you know, or ask for the comment to be deleted.